# How to mock send() in order to Unit Test the function commSendPacket?

Tags: c, unit-testing

Below is a C function to send data over socket connection.

```
void commSendPacket(unsigned char *send_buf,unsigned int len)
    {
     printf("\nIn comsendpacket\n");
     unsigned int send_bytes;
     send_bytes=send(gnew_sockfd,send_buf,len,0);

     printf("Bytes Send :%d\n",send_bytes);

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write a new source file `mock_send.c`. In this file implement the mock function of send, which does basically nothing. Link the testcase object with your mocked  send object, instead of the real one.